# Is Binary Domain playable without a mic?

Tags: binary-domain

Binary Domain has interested me for a while and is currently on sale at Steam.

Thing is, I've played the demo and came across a few occurences of dialog where I was supposed to answer to my teammates through a mic. Long story short, I don't have one, and the way my PC is set in my room makes it impractical to plug one in anyway.

I don't know if it's because it was a demo or a case of me not looking hard enough, but I couldn't find how or IF the voice system could be disabled, so any time one of these dialogs showed up I ended up being taken for a jerk by my teammates.

So, can I work around it? If so, how? Do I lose anything by playing without a mic?

Comment: The only thing the mic is good for is novelty. The recognition rate is poor and it takes longer than pressing a button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to several forum posts, voice commands can be disabled in settings.

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=30535272&postcount=12

http://forums.gametrailers.com/viewtopic.php?p=37177942#p37177942

Comment: Both links don't work

Comment: They’re over ten years old at this point.

Answer (score 6):

In game settings, put no for voice commands. Any voice command shown when you hold Tab will now show a key for it.